# Is it bad to have setInterval running all the time?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Does a function like this slow performance or is it considered bad practice?

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(something){
       do something
    }
}, 100);
```

Seems to me it would be bad to have something constantly running in the background.

Comment: If there has to be sth run regularily, what other way would be there??

Comment: I don't know. I'm a beginner :o) but I will learn more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is running a set of instructions every so many milliseconds, so it can "slow things down," depending on how intensive the instructions are and how many other instructions the user is running from other processes or on your webpage.

It is bad practice if not necessary. If your app is an app that does a thing every so many milliseconds, then that is one way to accomplish it. If you are resigning to use it because you just can't figure out the correct way of doing your task, you should spend time to find and implement the correct way of doing your task, instead of harassing the user's CPU cycles.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. And yes I am doing because I can't figure out a better way!! Unfortunately!

Comment: Agreed. It depends what the function inside the setInterval is doing, and how time-sensitive the rest of the code base is. This is essentially the idea behind the digest loop in AngularJS, constantly checking for changes in the $scope and recalculating/redrawing the DOM. So, it can be useful, but it doesn't scale well.

Comment: @NewCodeMan Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Try asking about what you can't figure out, rather than asking about your proposed solution.

Comment: Ahh yes. I did on my last post.  How to control back button functionality in JS. But its such a broad topic answered 100 dif ways.  So I am trying many and ran into this concern.